# Validity of approximating a difference equation with a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, recurrence-relations

Consider the following two equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
A_k(n+1)-A_k(n)=\beta  \displaystyle \frac{ A_{k-1}(n)- A_k(n)}{\alpha+  n} + \delta_{k, \beta}
\\ \\
\displaystyle
\frac{\partial{B_k(t)}}{\partial t}= 
\beta \frac{B_{k-1}(t)-  B_k(t)}{\alpha+  t} + \delta_{k ,\beta}
\end{cases}
\\ \\
$$
  The   first equation is a two-dimensional difference equation (in $k$ and $n$ domains), and the  second equation is its time-continuous analog. In the first equation, $n$ and $k$ are nonnegative integers. In the second equation, $k$ is nonnegative integer and $t\geq 0$ is continuous. The parameter   $\beta$ is a positive  integer, and $\delta_{\cdot ,\cdot}$ is the Kronecker delta function. Also, $\alpha>0$ is a constant.
At $t=n=0$, we have $A_k(0)=B_k(0)$ for all $k$.

Note that, although $B_k(t)$ is continuous in time, we can look at its values at integer times. Consider $t=n$, where $n>0$ is an integer. Can we find an upper bound on $|A_k(n)-B_k(n)|$ as a function of $n$?